# java fastest concurrent random file R/W method for SSDs without memory swap

Tags: java, file, random, solid-state-drive

I have a linux box with 32GB of ram and a set of 4 SSD in a raid 0 config that maxes out at about 1GB of throughput (random 4k reads) and I am trying to determine the best way of accessing files on them randomly and conccurently using java. The two main ways I have seen so far are via random access file and mapped direct byte buffers.

Heres where it gets tricky though. I have my own memory cache for objects so any call to the objects stored in a file should go through to disk and not paged memory (I have disabled the swap space on my linux box to prevent this). Whilst mapped direct memory buffers are supposedly the fastest they rely on swapping which is not good because A) I am using all the free memory for the object cache, using mappedbytebuffers instead would incur a massive serialization overhead which is what the object cache is there to prevent.(My program is already CPU limited) B) with mappedbytebuffers the OS handles the details of when data is written to disk, I need to control this myself, ie. when I write(byte[]) it goes straight out to disk instantly, this is to prevent data corruption incase of power failure as I am not using ACID transactions.

On the other hand I need massive concurrency, ie. I need to read and write to multiple locations in the same file at the same time (whilst using offset/Range locks to prevent data corruption) I'm not sure how I can do this without mappedbytebuffers, I could always just que the reads/Writes but I'm not sure how this will negatively affect my throughput.

Finally I can not have a situation when I am creating new byte[] objects for reads or writes, this is because I perform almost a 100000 read/write operations per second, allocating and Garbage collecting all those objects would kill my program which is time sensitive and already CPU limited, reusing byte[] objects is fine through.

Please do not suggest any DB software as I have tried most of them and they add to much complexity and cpu overhead.

Anybody had this kind of dilemma?

Comment: To me it sounds like you need more physical boxes. If you're already maxing out the CPU, RAM and SSD bandwidth it doesn't sound like you can get much more out of the box you have.

Comment: MappedByteBuffer.force() can force the updated data flushing into disk file.

Answer (score 3):

> Whilst mapped direct memory buffers are supposedly the fastest they rely on swapping

No, not if you have enough RAM. The mapping associates pages in memory with pages on disk. Unless the OS decides that it needs to recover RAM, the pages won't be swapped out. And if you are running short of RAM, all that disabling swap does is cause a fatal error rather than a performance degradation.

> I am using all the free memory for the object cache

Unless your objects are extremely long-lived, this is a bad idea because the garbage collector will have to do a lot of work when it runs. You'll often find that a smaller cache results in higher overall throughput.

> with mappedbytebuffers the OS handles the details of when data is written to disk, I need to control this myself, ie. when I write(byte[]) it goes straight out to disk instantly

Actually, it doesn't, unless you've mounted your filesystem with the `sync` option. And then you still run the risk of data loss from a failed drive (especially in RAID 0).

> I'm not sure how I can do this without mappedbytebuffers

A `RandomAccessFile` will do this. However, you'll be paying for at least a kernel context switch on every write (and if you have the filesystem mounted for synchronous writes, each of those writes will involve a disk round-trip).

> I am not using ACID transactions

Then I guess the data isn't really that valuable. So stop worrying about the possibility that someone will trip over a power cord.

Answer (score 1):

Your objections to mapped byte buffers don't hold up.  Your mapped files will be distinct from your object cache, and though they take address space they don't consume RAM.  You can also sync your mapped byte buffers whenever you want (at the cost of some performance).  Moreover, random access files end up using the same apparatus under the covers, so you can't save any performance there.

If mapped bytes buffers aren't getting you the performance you need, you might have to bypass the filesystem and write directly to raw partitions (which is what DBMS' do).  To do that, you probably need to write C++ code for your data handling and access it through JNI.